# Get value from multiple form fields in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to get value of multiple form controls which wraps `mat-select` with multiple options. I'm expecting to get array of `EntityParams` objects and add each time a new object of array whenever user selects one of the checkboxes.

```
export interface EntityParams  {
    key : string;
    value : string;
}
```

`key` should represent formControlName and `value` should be selected string inside specific form field. Every time user select checkbox in field new entry of `EntityParams` should be added to list.

As I'm creating form fields dynamicly as components, I wrapping them inside `form`:

***home.component.html:***

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="form" novalidate>
        <div class="filter-field" *ngFor="let filter of filters; let i = index">
          <app-filter-opt [options]="filters[i]" (selectedOptions)="filterMessages($event)"
            [isLoadingOptions]="isLoadingOptions"></app-filter-opt>
        </div>
</form>
```

***filter-opt.component.html:***

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="none" formControlName="{{filter.endpoint}}">
  <mat-select #filterSelect (openedChange)="openedChange($event , searchControl)" placeholder="All {{filter.name}}"
    multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{filterControl.value ? filteredValue : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="filterControl.value?.length > 1" class="additional-selection">
        (+{{filterControl.value.length - 1}} {{filterControl.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <div class="select-container">
      <div class="filter-header" (click)="filterSelect.close()">{{ filter.name }}</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>

      <mat-option (click)="unselectAll(filterControl)" [value]="{ code: 00 , name: ''}">
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>Unselect All
      </mat-option>

      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <div class="input-container" *ngIf="filter.expanded">
        <mat-optgroup>
          <mat-form-field style="width:100%;" floatLabel="never" appearance="none">
            <input matInput autocomplete="off" class="input-field" placeholder="Search" [formControl]="searchControl">
            <button [disableRipple]="true" *ngIf="searchControl.value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
              (click)="clearSearch($event, searchControl)">
              <mat-icon color="primary">close</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-optgroup>
      </div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>


      <mat-optgroup *ngIf="isLoadingOptions">
        <div class="select-placeholder-container"> <span>Loading...</span>
          <mat-spinner matPrefix class="spinner" diameter="20"></mat-spinner>
        </div>
      </mat-optgroup>

      <mat-option #opt *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="opt.selected">close</mat-icon> {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

As you can see I'm currently using `FormGroup`, I not sure if it is the right way to do it or I should use `FormArray`, but I am adding the form fields to form dynamicly
and listening for the value changes of whatever form field that was modified

***home.component.ts:***

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filters = this.loadFilterOptions();

    this.filters.forEach((filter) => {
      this.form.addControl(filter.endpoint, new FormControl())
    })

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})
  }
```

Unfortunately, this does not work I am receiving this error:

*ERROR Error: NG01052: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.*

My goal is to get form fields values whenever they change and send this `EntityParams` key-value as params inside the call. E.g `http://localhost:4200/dashboard?fuel-types=B04` where `fuel-types` is the key of formControlName and `B04` is the actuall value selected inside the form field.

Comment: the form doesn't *see inside* `app-filter-opt` so your home component thinks you haven't declared any form controls inside the form. Any reason you can't put the form group inside  `app-filter-opt` and handle data with inputs and outputs?

Comment: `app-filter-opt` is reusable component and its has search input for spefic form field to filter selection, so I am not sure if that would work